# Error in converting streams

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, isolatedstorage

I try to get an image stream from `IsolatedStorage` then assign it a bitmap image, like this:

```
using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, isolatedStorage))
{
    BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
    image.SetSource(fileStream);
    return image;
}
```

But in `image.SetSource(fileStream)` line, I get this error:

> The component cannot be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x88982F50)

**Update** I removed using block, and still the error occurs just exactly when it reaches to that line. Maybe I write the file incorrectly at first place?. this is what I do for saving file:

```
IsolatedStorageFile isolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

if (!isolatedStorage.DirectoryExists("MyImages"))
{
    isolatedStorage.CreateDirectory("MyImages");
}

var filePath = Path.Combine("MyImages", name + ".jpg");

using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, isolatedStorage))
{
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fileStream);
    sw.Write(image);
    sw.Close();
}
```

Comment: I don't remember if `SetSource` loads the content immediately or at a later time. Can you try without disposing the stream? (without the `using` block)

Comment: The HResult is produced when it cannot find the decoder for the image file.  Which could certainly be explained by you jerking the floor mat and disposing the file before BitmapImage has a chance to even read the file.

Comment: @HansPassant Bullseye, looks like it's not a valid picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code to save the picture is wrong. You're writing the result of `image.ToString()`, not the actual image. As a rule of thumb, remember that `StreamWriter` is used to write strings into a stream. Never try to use it to write binary data.

```
using (var isolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
    using (var fileStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, isolatedStorage))
    {
        var bitmap = new WriteableBitmap(image, null);
        bitmap.SaveJpeg(fileStream, bitmap.PixelWidth, bitmap.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
    }
}
```